# Hide dropdowns that only have 1 option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I hide the list items that have a dropdown with only have 1 option? Below, I want to hide the 1st and 3rd but can't figure this out. Can anyone help?

```
<li>
  <label>Test 1</label>
  <select>
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select</option>
  </select>
</li>
<li>
  <label>Test 2</label>
  <select>
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Option 1</option>
  </select>
</li>
<li>
  <label>Test 3</label>
  <select>
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

Comment: I tried this: $('li select').size()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('option').length === 1; 
}).closest('li').hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's  quick one liner without using each or filter:

```
$('select').not(':has(option:eq(1))').parent().remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nBTg6/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You could brute force it and just loop all the select boxes and check to see how many options are in each and hide it if there aren't enough.

```
var selectBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var length = selectBoxes.length;
var i = 0;

for (; i < length; i++) {
  if (selectBoxes[i].options.length < 2) {
    selectBoxes[i].parentNode.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

This code is untested, but should give you a general idea.